# Let $A(t), (a_{ij}): \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a periodic matrix with period $1$. Prove a solution to $x'=Ax$ is bounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question**
>
> Let $A(t), (a_{ij}): \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a periodic $n\times n$ matrix with period $1$.
>
> Prove that if $x(t)$ is a solution to $$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)\tag 1$$ defined on $\Bbb R$, witch satisfies $x(1)=-x(0)$, then $x$ is bounded.

**Attempt**

I had no idea on how to face this so I just tried the first thing that came to mind.

I thought evaluating the equation at $t\mapsto t+1$, we see that $x_1(t)=x(t+1)$ is a solution to $(1)$, and $x_1(0)=x(1)$. Suppose that $x(t+n)$ is a solution to $(1)$, thus
$$
x(t+n)=A(t)x(t+n)
$$

By induction, setting $t\mapsto t+1$, we get that $x_n(t)=x(t+n)$ is a solution to $(1)$ for all $n$, and that $x_n(0)=x(n)$. I got stuck there, and I don't think I'll get anywhere this way...

Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Show that $x(t+1) \equiv - x(t)$

${\bf Added}$

Note that if $x(t)$ is any solution of the equation then by substituting $t \mapsto t+1$ we still have 
$$x'(t+1) = A(t+1) x(t+1)$$

Let $y(t)= x(t+1)$. Then $y'(t) = x'(t+1)$ by (an easy) chain rule so we have
$$y'(t) = A(t+1) y(t)$$

Recall now that $A(t+1) \equiv A(t)$. We therefore get
$$y'(t) = A(t) y(t)$$

Now, together with $y(t)$, $z(t) =-y(t)= -x(t+1)$ is also a solution ( since the equation is linear).

So far this worked for every solution $x(t)$. Let now consider that solution for which $x(1) = -x(0)$. Recall that $z(t) = - x(t+1)$ is also a solution. Moreover , $z(0) = - x(0+1) = - x(1) = x(0)$. Now, by uniqueness we conclude that $z(t) \equiv x(t)$, that is $-x(t+1) \equiv x(t)$, or $x(t+1) \equiv - x(t)$

So $$x(t+2) \equiv x((t+1)+1) \equiv - x(t+1) \equiv x(t)$$

Comment: That would imply that $x\equiv 0$, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: No, but you would conclude that $x(t+2) = x(t)$ so $x$ is periodic ( and continuous) so bounded.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't prove it, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I think I got it! $\hat x :=x(t+1)+x(t)$ is a solution and $\hat x (0)=0$, so we get that $\hat x\equiv 0$, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Yes, that is also a very good way, great!